# LIKE Wild Card Search in Teradata

Tags: sql, wildcard, teradata

I have text in a column like `RAPP 01`. `RAPP 02` upto `RAPP 45` and `RAPP 99`.I included all these values manually in my IN statement in my WHERE clause but it slows the query as the data set in huge. I tried `WHERE SUBSTR(REMARK_TXT,1,7) LIKE 'RIPA [01-45,99]'` and it did not return any data. Can you please help?
Thanks!

Comment: A typo? RIPA <> RAPP

Comment: Does Teradata understand brackets in `LIKE`? I thought that was a T-SQL-only thing.

Comment: Depending on your actual data you could use `SUBSTR(REMARK_TXT,1,7) BETWEEN 'RAPP 01' AND 'RAPP 45' OR SUBSTR(REMARK_TXT,1,7) = 'RAPP 99'` or `WHERE REMARK_TXT LIKE 'RIPA %' AND CAST(SUBSTR(REMARK_TXT,6,2) AS INT) IN (1-45,99)`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: No, it only supports Standard SQL `%_`, but you can apply a Regular Expression function.

Comment: Thanks! SUBSTR(REMARK_TXT,1,7) BETWEEN 'RAPP 01' AND 'RAPP 45' OR SUBSTR(REMARK_TXT,1,7) = 'RAPP 99' worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use REGEXP functionality here:

```
 WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR(REMARK_TXT, '^RAPP [0-9]{2}$') = 1;
```

That regex matches with a string that starts with `RAPP` followed by a space then followed by 2 numbers and the end of the string.

---

Updating to deal with two number ranges (01-49) and (99). This isn't the best thing to do with regex, but it's still possible:

```
 WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR(REMARK_TXT, '^RAPP ([0-4][0-9]|99)$') = 1;
```

This is saying a string that starts with `RAPP` and then ends in either a two digit number that starts with 0 through 4 OR the number 99

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I just want to look at RAPP 01-45 and RAPP 99 alone. Is there a way to integrate this in the REGEXP you had  mentioned?

Comment: I've updated the answer to deal with the number ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
where column like ('RAPP %')
```

Which would return anything beginning with the string `RAPP` and a whitespace. Notice the '`%`' sign, this will be your wildcard.
Careful on using `like`, especially `not like` and putting the wildcard at the beginning of your condition, it would have much bigger performance issues.